# Accessing properties of unnamed objects (within an object)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Javascript/JQuery to consume a Google web service, and can retrieve the JSON results with no problem, storing them in a var (named searchResults). In this example, I'm just adding all the info I want to display from the object (long_name in each sub-object of address_components, and the lat & lng values) to a string var (displayTxt).

However, there are many unnamed objects within the results, and I can't find an easy way to target them. I'd like to use the standard object.property syntax, although if the object isn't named (and there's more than one of them) that isn't possible. I've resorted to looping through each successive object using embedded $.each loops, and this solution does work, however I don't think it's very tidy. So my question is: Is there a better way of achieving the same result?

```
$( "#displayBtn" ).click(function()
 {
    var displayTxt = "";
    if (searchResults.results)
        {

            $.each(searchResults.results, function (k,v)
                   {
                    displayTxt +=( "Result ID: " + k + "<br>");
                    $.each(v,function(a,b)
                           {
                            if(a=="address_components")
                                { 
                                $.each(b,function(c,d)
                                       {
                                        displayTxt += (d.long_name + "<br>")
                                        })
                                }
                            })
                    displayTxt+= "lat:" + v.geometry.location.lat +"<br>";
                    displayTxt+= "lng:" + v.geometry.location.lng +"<br><br>";
                   }
                  )

        };
     $('#resultsDisplay').html(displayTxt); 
});
```

and here's the searchResults object:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Exeter",
           "short_name" : "Exeter",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Berks County",
           "short_name" : "Berks County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Pennsylvania",
           "short_name" : "PA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Reading, PA, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.371134,
              "lng" : -75.890512
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.296401,
              "lng" : -75.9598731
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.3356483,
           "lng" : -75.9268747
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.371134,
              "lng" : -75.890512
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.296401,
              "lng" : -75.9598731
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "England",
           "short_name" : "England",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
           "short_name" : "GB",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Reading, Reading, Reading, UK",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 51.4931339,
              "lng" : -0.9284944000000001
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 51.4097795,
              "lng" : -1.0636011
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 51.4542645,
           "lng" : -0.9781303
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 51.4931339,
              "lng" : -0.9284944000000001
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 51.4097795,
              "lng" : -1.0636011
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Middlesex County",
           "short_name" : "Middlesex County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Massachusetts",
           "short_name" : "MA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Reading, MA, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 42.566432,
              "lng" : -71.07103499999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 42.5006449,
              "lng" : -71.1361789
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 42.5256563,
           "lng" : -71.0952891
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 42.566432,
              "lng" : -71.07103499999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 42.5006449,
              "lng" : -71.1361789
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Hamilton County",
           "short_name" : "Hamilton County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ohio",
           "short_name" : "OH",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Reading, OH, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 39.240921,
              "lng" : -84.407549
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 39.2038819,
              "lng" : -84.454735
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 39.2236694,
           "lng" : -84.44216410000001
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 39.240921,
              "lng" : -84.407549
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 39.2038819,
              "lng" : -84.454735
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Windsor County",
           "short_name" : "Windsor County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Vermont",
           "short_name" : "VT",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Reading, VT, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.561169,
              "lng" : -72.53007579999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.4440849,
              "lng" : -72.66064299999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.494167,
           "lng" : -72.59638900000002
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.561169,
              "lng" : -72.53007579999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.4440849,
              "lng" : -72.66064299999999
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Reading",
           "short_name" : "Reading",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Summit Lake",
           "short_name" : "Summit Lake",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Nobles County",
           "short_name" : "Nobles County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Minnesota",
           "short_name" : "MN",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "56165",
           "short_name" : "56165",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Reading, MN 56165, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.7035752,
           "lng" : -95.7130676
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.70492418029149,
              "lng" : -95.71171861970849
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.70222621970849,
              "lng" : -95.71441658029151
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unnamed objects?" It sure sounds like you're talking about working with elements of arrays...

Comment: The result contains arrays of objects, so you're stuck with iterating through those arrays.

Comment: In hindsight, I have to agree. JavaScript newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you have an array of objects, which don't have names (they aren't assigned to variables, just part of an array). You do have a few different options for iterating over arrays, though.

The classic iterator is a for loop using the length, such as:

```js
var data = [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}, {value: 4}, {value: 5}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  console.log(data[i].value);
}
```

This will log each item as it's encountered, and uses the array index to access them. It doesn't matter what the item is, you simply change the logic within the array. As with `$.each`, you can nest these loops (just make sure to use a different variable).

If you have access to some of the new JS features, a `forEach` method has been added to arrays, which allows you to do:

```js
var data = [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}, {value: 4}, {value: 5}];

data.forEach(function(it) {
  console.log(it.value);
});
```

This is much more like `$.each`, but is built-in on arrays, and doesn't have the same semantics when iterating over DOM elements and the like. Again, you can nest these, but there's no counter to worry about. This is the recommended way, if it's available.

Either way, once you have the item (by accessing it from the array), you have a "name" for it (it's been assigned to a variable) and you can use normal object-access syntax to get at properties within the object.

If you want to transform the data into a new array or combine the elements into a single return value, you may look into methods like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), now available on arrays (and previously from libraries such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/)).

Comment: That's explained it well, thanks. I wasn't looking at items like "results" "address_components" correctly as arrays, but as "objects with objects inside", which caused the confusion. I'm going to try the results.forEach() method.